# Is it ideal to run two aerospike instances on the same server box?

Tags: aerospike

I'm planning to run two instances of aerospike on the same server on two different ports, so as to use it for two of my services. I want to know if using such a setup is ideally and practically a correct approach or not.

Please suggest what would be the ideal setup for this. Should I use two different servers for the two instances then?

Answer (score 2):

Its all about uptime, redundancy and performance. If that one server goes down, you lose both services. Ideally, you would deploy a single Aerospike cluster on 3 different servers with replication factor 2 *at a minimum* so if any one server goes down, you still have full access to all your data and service availability. Can you deploy two Aerospike clusters on 3 physical servers with port separation? sure you can - alternative would be to define 2 different namespaces in a single Aerospike cluster and each service uses different namespace. So separate services by namespace instead of port. The other impact is latency performance - how activities on one service will impact performance of the other service because of shared server resources - that depends on what the requirements are and what the services are doing.

Comment: Even if I make two namespaces, if one namespace meets some issue which takes that instance of aerospike down, I'll lose the whole instance which has the other namespace as well right?

I was more afraid of the instance being shut rather than the server being shut.

Comment: If you size your server correctly for your data load, you don't OOM the instance. What you say is true - if instance OOMs, all namespaces go down. But there are folks running Aerospike un-interrupted for years.  When you launch two instances, each will consume its own runtime memory and other machine resources, so you will be worse off "sizing the server" wise.  BTW, good question from application design for multi-tenancy point of view, not sure why moderators flagged this as a bad question.